# Using Select From table in Insert statement of a merge query

Tags: sql-server, azure

The below code is getting error in SQL

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

This is my code for merge where InstalledSoftwareList is a used defined table.

```
 MERGE [dbo].[TableName] AS TargetTable      
        USING UDTableName AS SourceTable                    
        ON (TargetTable.[EId] = SourceTable.[EId]
        AND TargetTable.[MId] = SourceTable.[MId]
        AND TargetTable.PackageId = (SELECT Id FROM [PackagesDummyTable] SP WHERE SP.[Version] = SourceTable.[Version] AND SP.[Name] = SourceTable.[Name])
        )    

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET                                -- If the records in the Customer table is not matched?-- then INSERT the record
            THEN INSERT ([Guid], [PackageId], [CName], [UUID], [MAC], [Date], [isUninstalled], [LastUpdatedDateTime], [DataCapturedTime], [SGuid], [UniqueId], [MId], [EId])
                Select SourceTable.Guid,SP.PackageId,SourceTable.CName,SourceTable.UUID,SourceTable.MAC,SourceTable.Date,SourceTable.isUninstalled,GETUTCDATE(),SourceTable.DataCapturedTime,SourceTable.SGuid, SourceTable.UniqueId, SourceTable.MId, SourceTable.EId
                FROM [PackagesDummyTable] SP WHERE SP.[Version] = SourceTable.[Version] AND SP.[Name] = SourceTable.[Name];
```

I was referring this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx. And my syntax seems to be right.
Can anyone help me on this. I am using SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gotqn said, If you only need to prcess the new data, you can just you insert into statement.

If it's required that you must you MERG INTo, you can change your script to below

```
    MERGE [dbo].[TableName] AS TargetTable      
    USING (
            SELECT UN.[EId],UN.[MId],SP.ID ,UN.Guid,SP.PackageId,UN.CName,UN.UUID,UN.MAC,UN.Date,UN.isUninstalled
                  ,UN.DataCapturedTime,UN.SGuid, UN.UniqueId
            FROM  UDTableName AS UN AS 
            INNER JOIN  [PackagesDummyTable] SP  ON SP.[Version] = UN.[Version] AND SP.[Name] = UN.[Name]  
         )  SourceTable          
    ON TargetTable.[EId] = SourceTable.[EId]
    AND TargetTable.[MId] = SourceTable.[MId]
    AND TargetTable.PackageId = SourceTable.Id

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET                                -- If the records in the Customer table is not matched?-- then INSERT the record
        THEN INSERT ([Guid], [PackageId], [CName], [UUID], [MAC], [Date], [isUninstalled], [LastUpdatedDateTime], [DataCapturedTime], [SGuid], [UniqueId], [MId], [EId])
            VALUES( SourceTable.Guid,SourceTable.PackageId,SourceTable.CName,SourceTable.UUID,SourceTable.MAC,SourceTable.Date,SourceTable.isUninstalled,GETUTCDATE(),SourceTable.DataCapturedTime,SourceTable.SGuid, SourceTable.UniqueId, SourceTable.MId, SourceTable.EId)
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is nice if you want to do more than one `CRUD` operations. In this case, we only need to insert new records. Could you try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ([Guid], [PackageId], [CName], [UUID], [MAC], [Date], [isUninstalled], [LastUpdatedDateTime], [DataCapturedTime], [SGuid], [UniqueId], [MId], [EId])
SELECT SourceTable.Guid,SP.PackageId,SourceTable.CName,SourceTable.UUID,SourceTable.MAC,SourceTable.Date,SourceTable.isUninstalled,GETUTCDATE(),SourceTable.DataCapturedTime,SourceTable.SGuid, SourceTable.UniqueId, SourceTable.MId, SourceTable.EId
-- we need these two tables in order to import data
FROM UDTableName AS SourceTable     
INNER JOIN [PackagesDummyTable] SP 
    ON SP.[Version] = SourceTable.[Version] 
    AND SP.[Name] = SourceTable.[Name]
-- we are joing this table in order to check if there is new data for import
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TableName] AS TargetTable  
    ON TargetTable.[EId] = SourceTable.[EId]
    AND TargetTable.[MId] = SourceTable.[MId]
-- we are importing only the data that is new
WHERE TargetTable.PackageId IS NULL;
```

Comment: I want to process new as well as existing data.